# Is it safe to operate with and return dynamic arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

```
/*
 * Example function for operating with dynamic arguments
 */
function something(){
    for(var i in arguments){
        arguments[i] = arguments[i] + Math.random() * 25;
    }

    return arguments;
}
```

There are no errors, have not noticed performance drops, and, the values are changed.

So, is it safe to do such operations on dynamic arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would never return it since it's not a real array (see http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/ for some information about special behaviour of that object) - so depending on what the calling code does with it, it would fail.

However, you can easily turn it into an array:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

I would not modify the original object since changes also change the corresponding named arguments in case your function accepts any.

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is a "pseudo-array". How would it be different from returning an array? The only downside is that `arguments` is not an array and therefore, you don't have the array properties and methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe. Yet, you should beware of the functionality of the `arguments` object, which differs between Ecmascript implementations and versions. It can be a pseudo-array linked absolutely to the argument variables, but also can be a independent Array instance.

If you know your environment it's OK, elsewhile it's better to code

```
function something() {
    var l = arguments.length,
        res = new Array(l);
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        res[i] = arguments[i] + Math.random() * 25;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It'd be better to use ThiefMasters variant in such case.

Comment: Why would you use slice to copy it, if you don't need these values anyway? http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-create

Comment: <strike>But you are creating a new Array and adding those values dynamically, that's the same as with slice, except inside a loop.</strike> Huh, didn't notice the jsperf link before... Interesting. Would it be faster on all browsers?

Comment: nah, I'm creating an *empty* array while slice needs to copy the values into it. If you just need the arguments as an Array, slice surely is the better option.